# Fail to add element to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on this [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/employee-importance).

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

// Employee info
class Employee {
    // It's the unique id of each node;
    // unique id of this employee
    public int id;
    // the importance value of this employee
    public int importance;
    // the id of direct subordinates
    public List<Integer> subordinates;
};

class Solution {
    public int getImportance(List<Employee> employees, int id) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> subordinates = new HashMap<>();

        // put value and subordinates into maps
        for(Employee employee : employees) {
            int e_id = employee.id;
            int value = employee.importance;
            List<Integer> subordinate = employee.subordinates;
            values.put(id, value);
            subordinates.put(id, subordinate);
        }

        // find suborinates and add up the values
        List<Integer> subs = subordinates.getOrDefault(id, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        int total_value = values.getOrDefault(id, 0);

        for(int sub_id : subs){
            total_value = total_value + values.getOrDefault(sub_id, 0);
        }

        return total_value;
    }
}
public class Sixninezero {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.id = 3;
        e1.importance = 3;
        List<Integer> list_e1 = new ArrayList<>();
        e1.subordinates = list_e1;

        Employee e2 = new Employee();
        e2.id = 2;
        e2.importance = 5;
        List<Integer> list_e2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list_e2.add(3);
        e2.subordinates = list_e2;

        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(e1);
        employees.add(e2);

        Solution solution = new Solution();
        int result = solution.getImportance(employees, 2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

I created two Employee objects and added them into an ArrayList named `employees`, then I passed the `employees` to the `getImportance()` method. In this method, the for loop would go through the `employees` and put the `id` and corresponding  `value(importance)` pair into the map named `values`, and did similar to `subordinates` map. So each `values` and `subordinates` should have 2 elements because the `employees` has two objects. But it always has one element (the second one). I think I did right when for loop an ArrayList, is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the Employee Id for both employees? Is it same? Share what you are adding to employee list as employee data.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the `id` from the method argument into the `values` map, every time through the loop.
It looks like you should be doing this instead:

```
values.put( e_id, value );
subordinates.put( e_id, subordinate );
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: oops! I forgot to change all ids to e_id when I made the change. Thank you so much!